# setVisibility true of dynamic id of a layout

Tags: android, listview, visibility

I have created `ListView` in which each button id comprises of **database_idx10+button_number**

For example, I have set the id as 101 i.e. 10=**database_id** & 1=**button_number**

Now I've to `setVisibility` of id `101` to `View.GONE` which is a unique id generated by me.

How can I use this generated id to set visibility true.

I am retriving this id by calling a user define function "click" and in xml I have set `android:onClick="click"`

```
public void click(View view) {
    final int position = view.getId();
    int button_number = position % 10;
    int id = position/10;
    int layout_id=id*10+2;

    if(button_number==1){
        //have to set visibity true of layout_id
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

> I was able to set visibility from visible to gone  button but not the
>   opposite.

Comment: Considering that you are setting the onClickListener in getView method, you should also write the else condition after "if", which will make the view invisible, because the views are recycled and retain the previous properties.

Comment: @SarthakMittal `android:onClick="click"` in xml not in getView  method

Comment: ok, but that's a list item right? if it is, then also add the else statement

Comment: it is just part of the code related to my question but will keep in mind

Comment: Why its necessary to set an unique id to each of your button in each list items you have in your list?

Comment: how will we uniquely define them? @ReazMurshed

Comment: You don't have to uniquely define them. That's the beauty of `ListView` actually. I would like to give an answer describing the alternative way. It won't be the solution of your question though.

Comment: thanks a lot @ReazMurshed

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if that's clear to you.

Comment: Can you show your `ListView` adapter code and item xml layout code?

Comment: @KNeerajLal http://pastebin.com/LnAJmJxN here it is

Comment: Which is the button which you are trying to click and which is the one you are trying to hide?

Comment: I am trying to display layout android:id="@+id/details" which is initially hidden @KNeerajLal

Comment: On click of textview1 this should happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this button is Child of your view object you can do something like this

```
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(your_id);
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Or if not you have to findById this view in his parent layout or in activity.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: using code ` View btn = view.findViewById(layout_id);
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: Explain your view structure. You have buttons in ListView and you want to change another view visibility after button click right? This another view is ListView child od this is separate view in activity or fragment?

Comment: the problem is originally i have set `android:visibility="gone"` so the button or layout is not present in the ,what u call DOM

Comment: issue object absent in the dom/body  @ReazMurshed

Comment: @Szwed i am able to set visible gone to visible button but not vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution of the question asked, but anyway to uniquely identify a button in your list item is easy. You don't have to set unique IDs yourself actually. The `View` reference of each button in your list is different already. You just have to identify them using the `position` in your `getView` method.

Here's a sample `getView` method of the adapter in your list.

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if( convertView == null ){
        //We must create a View:
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    // Here we can do changes to the convertView
    Button b = convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    // Set your visibility here
    if(your_condition_is_true) b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else b.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` how you are targeting a specific id or button?

Comment: `getView` will be called when ever i click anything  in list?

Comment: i don't have to do this when creating list i want to do on a click event

Comment: `getView` binds each of your list items. The `onClick` will be set as `convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_button).setOnClickListener(...)` on each list item.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this 
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: where will i set this ?

Comment: public void click(View view) {
    final int position = view.getId();
    int button_number = position % 10;
    int id = position/10;
    int layout_id=id*10+2;

    if(button_number==1){
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need a `boolean` variable in the `Details` class to hold the visibility of the details section.

Your adapter code should be,

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Details> list;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Details> result2) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = result2;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView topic;
        TextView detail;
        LinearLayout details;
        ImageButton send;
        ImageButton edit;
        ImageButton delete;

        public Holder(View v) {
            this.topic= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            this.detail= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.td);
            this.details = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.details);
            this.send= (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
            this.edit= (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton3);
            this.delete= (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View row=view;
        Holder holder=null;
        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(MainActivity.context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout,viewGroup,false);
            holder = new Holder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder= (Holder) row.getTag();
        }

        final Details temp = (Details) getItem(i);

        holder.topic.setText(temp.getTopic());
        holder.detail.setText(temp.getTopic_details());

        if(temp.isDetailButtonVisible()){
            holder.details.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.details.setVisiblity(View.GONE);         
        }

        holder.topic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                temp.setDetailButtonVisibility(false);
            }
        });

        holder.send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        holder.detail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });



        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        return row;
    }


}
```

You layout should be,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#5894CA"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:text="Bank of baroda details...."
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
                android:background="@drawable/share" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/imagebutton3"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gnome_edit_delete" />

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="148dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:text="I have a LinearLayout that I've styled to look like a button, and it contains a few text/ImageView elements. I would like to make the whole LinearLayout act like a button, in particular to give it states that are defined in a so it has a different background when it is pressed..."
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/td" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: isDetailButtonVisible method ?

Comment: Read the first line in my answer. `isDetailButtonVisible` is a wrapper to that variable.

Comment: temp.setDetailButtonVisibility(false); temp cannot be accessed by inner class

Comment: list.setAdapter(context,new MyAdapter(result2)); on Mainactivity giving error i dont know why

Comment: Try `list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context, result2));`